# SwiftUI: Сохранение переменной в модели при перезагрузки

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

У меня задача локально сохранить переменную `isLiked`, чтобы при перезагрузки приложения оставалось состояние, которое было указано (true/false)
Пытался сделать через @AppStorage и UserDefaults, но безуспешно. Буду благодарен, если поможете с реализацией данного вопроса!

Вот основная модель:

```
class Model: ObservableObject, Identifiable{
    
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var category: ModelCategory
    var salecategory: SaleCategory
    var name: String   //modelName
    var modelEntity: ModelEntity?
    var country: String
    var scaleCompensation: Float
    var photo: String
    var price: String
    var delivery: String
    var depth: String
    var description: String
    var height: String
    var material: String
    var link: String
    var company: String
    var ogrn: String
    var seller: String
    //var volume: String
    var width: String
    //var weight: String
    var colour: String
    var article: String
    var assembling: String
    var address: String
    var isLiked: Bool
    
    var readableDescription: String? {
        return description.removingHTMLOccurances
    }
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
```

Инициализация

```
 init(name: String,
         category: ModelCategory,
         salecategory: SaleCategory,
         scaleCompensation: Float = 1.0,
         country: String,
         photo: String,
         price: String,
         delivery: String,
         depth: String,
         description: String,
         height: String,
         material: String,
         link: String,
         company: String,
         ogrn: String,
         seller: String,
         //volume: String,
         width: String,
         //weight: String,
         colour: String,
         article: String,
         assembling: String,
         address: String,
         isLiked: Bool)
    
    {
        self.name = name
        self.scaleCompensation = scaleCompensation
        self.country = country
        self.photo = photo
        self.price = price
        self.salecategory = salecategory
        self.category = category
        self.delivery = delivery
        self.depth = depth
        self.description = description
        self.height = height
        self.material = material
        self.link = link
        self.company = company
        self.ogrn = ogrn
        self.seller = seller
        //self.volume = volume
        self.width = width
        //self.weight = weight
        self.colour = colour
        self.article = article
        self.assembling = assembling
        self.address = address
        self.isLiked = isLiked
    }
```

Новый класс, который использую для обращения, к основной модели

```
class ModelsViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var models = [Model]()
    @Published var card: Model!
    
    init() {
            self.models = documents.map {(QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Model  in
                let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let delivery = data["delivery"] as? String ?? ""
                let depth = data["depth"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                let height = data["height"] as? String ?? ""
                let material = data["material"] as? String ?? ""
                let link = data["link"] as? String ?? ""
                let company = data["company"] as? String ?? ""
                let ogrn = data["ogrn"] as? String ?? ""
                let seller = data["seller"] as? String ?? ""
                //let volume = data["volume"] as? String ?? ""
                let width = data["width"] as? String ?? ""
                //let weight = data["weight"] as? String ?? ""
                let colour = data["colour"] as? String ?? ""
                let article = data["article"] as? String ?? ""
                let assembling = data["assembling"] as? String ?? ""
                let photo = data["photo"] as? String ?? ""
                let country = data["country"] as? String ?? ""
                let price = data["price"] as? String ?? ""
                let categoryText = data["category"] as? String ?? ""
                let salecategoryText = data["salecategory"] as? String ?? ""
                let category = ModelCategory(rawValue: categoryText) ?? .table
                let salecategory = SaleCategory(rawValue: salecategoryText) ?? .sale0
                let scaleCompensation = data["scaleCompensation"] as? Double ?? 1.0
                let address = data["address"] as? String ?? ""
                let isLiked = data["isLiked"] as? Bool ?? false
                
                return Model(name: name,
                             category: category,
                             salecategory: salecategory,
                             scaleCompensation: Float(scaleCompensation),
                             country: country,
                             photo: photo,
                             price: price,
                             delivery: delivery,
                             depth: depth,
                             description: description,
                             height: height,
                             material: material,
                             link: link,
                             company: company,
                             ogrn: ogrn,
                             seller: seller,
                             // volume: volume,
                             width: width,
                             //weight: weight,
                             colour: colour,
                             article: article,
                             assembling: assembling,
                             address: address,
                             isLiked: isLiked)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу прощения за громоздкий код, но оставил, чтобы ничего не потерять

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент ты получаешь данные для модели при инициализации. Поэтому они у тебя остаются неизменными - ты их забираешь одни и те же. UserDefaults вполне может сработать. Просто при инициализации нужно проверить есть ли данные в UserDefaults по твоему ключу и, если есть, взять их оттуда. Если нет - твой стандартный путь.